# Makefile - crosscompile problems

Tags: c, makefile, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

Im working with the BeagleBoneBlack and im making a device driver and a simple tcp server to send the data to a client.
The driver is a linux kernel module and the server runs on the beaglebone, but the client runs on the pc.

I was crosscompiling the driver on the pc and then transfering the driver.ko, server_tcp.c and server_tcp.h to the beglebone, to later compile the server in the beaglebone with gcc. 
Now im trying to compile both the kernel and the server on the pc and then only transfer the compiled files, but when executing the server im getting:

> bash: ./server_tcp: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

My makefile looks like this:

```
obj-m := ./driver/driver.o ./server/server_tcp.o
KERNEL_DIR := /home/user/kernel_beagle/
BEAGLEBONE_IP := 192.168.7.2
ARCH := arm
CROSS_COMPILE := arm-linux-gnueabihf-

MAKEARCH := $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE)

.PHONY : help
help:
    @echo ''
    @echo '  make all:      Compile and transfer'
    @echo '  make clean:    Delete files'
    @echo ''

.PHONY : all
all: 
    @echo 'Compile the driver'
    $(MAKEARCH) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules

    @echo 'Compile the client'
    gcc ./client/client.c -o ./client/client -pthread -lrt

    @echo 'Transfer files'
    scp ./server/server_tcp debian@$(BEAGLEBONE_IP):/home/debian

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo 'Deleting files'
    $(MAKEARCH) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) M=$(PWD) clean
    rm ./client/client
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see in this makefile the `server_tcp` target.

Comment: I forgot to add the _tcp when translating the makefile. Still have the problem.

Comment: I still don't see where it is built.

Comment: The message most likely means you are trying to run an executable built for your pc on the target device.  i.e. you ran the native compiler, not the cross compiler.  As Eugene says, there appears to no `server_tcp` target in the makefile, so we can't say why that happened.

Comment: Had to add: 
 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ./server/server_tcp.c -o ./server/server_tcp. Any cleaner way?

Comment: You need that line in one form or another. You can make it "cleaner" with some substitutions like `$(CROSS-COMPILE)gcc` , or by creating a more generic rule for all cross-compiled targets.